# Unity - ThirdPersonController - help implementing with my own models please

Tags: unity, 3d, input, interface

I've created a basic 3d character (humanoid) in Blender with animations etc. I've imported it into Unity and it works fine. However, I have written my own code to handle the CrossPlatformInput script that comes with the ThirdPersonController prefab in the Standard Assets Package.

I based the code off the same code that came with the Unity character, but it didnt work. The character rotates on the spot. Other than the fact he isnt moving anywhere, its actually really smooth how it rotates etc, im happy with the character and animation. I just need him to head in the direction im holding after turning (much like the Unity Standard Character does).

So I went about removing some of the code in the script for none essential stuff (ie. at the moment I dont need Crouch, or Jump.) hoping I could then figure out how to make him move 'forward' when holding the keys. (its important to note that the same script works fine when I drag the standard character in, but whenever I try attaching the script to my characters they just spin on the spot without moving.

I even tried adding some lines like rigidbody.AddForce(move) into the move method of the script.

I'm really stuck for last couple of days with this problem :(

It's also really difficult for me to know what to paste here to ask for help as a lot of it I have just used standard code, I'm wondering if my model needs something done to it??

Here is the code in question. If you need to say any other parts of my project id be happy to paste the whole project up somewhere so u could see exactly what I mean.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]
public class ThirdPersonPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] float m_MovingTurnSpeed = 360;
[SerializeField] float m_StationaryTurnSpeed = 180;
[SerializeField] float m_JumpPower = 12f;
[Range(1f, 4f)] [SerializeField] float m_GravityMultiplier = 2f;
[SerializeField] float m_RunCycleLegOffset = 0.2f; //specific to the character in sample assets, will need to be modified to work with others
[SerializeField] float m_MoveSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
[SerializeField] float m_AnimSpeedMultiplier = 1f;
[SerializeField] float m_GroundCheckDistance = 0.1f;

Rigidbody m_Rigidbody;
Animator m_Animator;
bool m_IsGrounded;
float m_OrigGroundCheckDistance;
const float k_Half = 0.5f;
float m_TurnAmount;
float m_ForwardAmount;
Vector3 m_GroundNormal;
float m_CapsuleHeight;
Vector3 m_CapsuleCenter;
CapsuleCollider m_Capsule;
bool m_Crouching;


void Start()
{
    m_Animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    m_Rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    m_Capsule = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();
    m_CapsuleHeight = m_Capsule.height;
    m_CapsuleCenter = m_Capsule.center;

    m_Rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;
    m_OrigGroundCheckDistance = m_GroundCheckDistance;
}


public void Move(Vector3 move, bool crouch, bool jump)
{

    // convert the world relative moveInput vector into a local-relative
    // turn amount and forward amount required to head in the desired
    // direction.
    if (move.magnitude > 1f) move.Normalize();
    move = transform.InverseTransformDirection(move);
    CheckGroundStatus();
    move = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(move, m_GroundNormal);
    m_TurnAmount = Mathf.Atan2(move.x, move.z);
    m_ForwardAmount = move.z;

    ApplyExtraTurnRotation();





}

void ApplyExtraTurnRotation()
{
    // help the character turn faster (this is in addition to root rotation in the animation)
    float turnSpeed = Mathf.Lerp(m_StationaryTurnSpeed, m_MovingTurnSpeed, m_ForwardAmount);
    transform.Rotate(0, m_TurnAmount * turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}

void CheckGroundStatus()
{
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    // helper to visualise the ground check ray in the scene view
    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f) + (Vector3.down * m_GroundCheckDistance));
#endif
    // 0.1f is a small offset to start the ray from inside the character
    // it is also good to note that the transform position in the sample assets is at the base of the character
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position + (Vector3.up * 0.1f), Vector3.down, out hitInfo, m_GroundCheckDistance))
    {
        m_GroundNormal = hitInfo.normal;
        m_IsGrounded = true;
        //m_Animator.applyRootMotion = true;
    }
    else
    {
        m_IsGrounded = false;
        m_GroundNormal = Vector3.up;
        //m_Animator.applyRootMotion = false;
    }
}
```

}

AND OTHER SCRIPT:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(ThirdPersonPlayer))]
public class ThirdPersonControl : MonoBehaviour
{
private ThirdPersonPlayer m_Character; // A reference to the ThirdPersonCharacter on the object
private Transform m_Cam;                  // A reference to the main camera in the scenes transform
private Vector3 m_CamForward;             // The current forward direction of the camera
private Vector3 m_Move;
private bool m_Jump;                      // the world-relative desired move direction, calculated from the camForward and user input.


private void Start()
{
    // get the transform of the main camera
    if (Camera.main != null)
    {
        m_Cam = Camera.main.transform;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.LogWarning(
            "Warning: no main camera found. Third person character needs a Camera tagged \"MainCamera\", for camera-relative controls.", gameObject);
        // we use self-relative controls in this case, which probably isn't what the user wants, but hey, we warned them!
    }

    // get the third person character ( this should never be null due to require component )
    m_Character = GetComponent<ThirdPersonPlayer>();
}


private void Update()
{
    if (!m_Jump)
    {
        m_Jump = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump");
    }
}


// Fixed update is called in sync with physics
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    // read inputs
    float h = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float v = CrossPlatformInputManager.GetAxis("Vertical");
    bool crouch = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.C);

    // calculate move direction to pass to character
    if (m_Cam != null)
    {
        // calculate camera relative direction to move:
        m_CamForward = Vector3.Scale(m_Cam.forward, new Vector3(1, 0, 1)).normalized;
        m_Move = v * m_CamForward + h * m_Cam.right;
    }
    else
    {
        // we use world-relative directions in the case of no main camera
        m_Move = v * Vector3.forward + h * Vector3.right;
    }
#if !MOBILE_INPUT
        // walk speed multiplier
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) m_Move *= 0.5f;
#endif

    // pass all parameters to the character control script
    m_Character.Move(m_Move, crouch, m_Jump);
    m_Jump = false;
}
```

}